# Moq unit tests : System.TypeInitializationException on Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory

Tags: c#, moq, castle-windsor

I'm using Moq as a mocking Library for my unit tests.

It seems it has a hard time finding the Castle Windsor libraries, as it gives me this error :

```
System.TypeInitializationException : Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'Moq.Mock`1'.
  ----> System.TypeInitializationException : Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory'.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
   à Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__24_0()
   à Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
   à Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
   à Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
   à Moq.Mock.GetObject()
   à Moq.Mock.get_Object()
   à Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
   à TecLib.Common.Tests.Infrastructure.CqrsRepositoryBaseTest.SetUp() dans C:\Users\Ludovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TEC2\TecLib.Common.Tests\Infrastructure\CqrsRepositoryBaseTest.cs:ligne 38
--TypeInitializationException
   à Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..ctor()
   à Moq.Mock`1..cctor()
--FileNotFoundException
   à Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory..cctor()
```

This is one of the tests that trigger the error. The code works perfectly fine. It's the Moq Library that triggers the error as it seems to not be able to find the Castle Windsor Library for some reason.

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _eventStore = new Mock<IEventStore>();
        _eventDispatcher = new Mock<IEventDispatcher>();
        _entityFactory = new Mock<IEntityFactory>();

        _repository = new CqrsAddressRepository(_entityFactory.Object, _eventStore.Object, _eventDispatcher.Object);
        _addressInfo1 = new AddressInfo("400 chemin Jette", "", "", "Farnham", "J0J2B0", "Quebec", "Canada");
        _addressInfo2 = new AddressInfo("322 rue Principale E", "", "", "Farnham", "J2N1L7", "Quebec", "Canada");
    }
```

These are my packages for that project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.5.21" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

These tests worked perfectly before. I have no idea what has changed that make them throw this error now.

Maybe installation of the 4.6.1 .net Framework ?

Please help!

Answer (score 7):

Your error message says:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Impossible de charger le fichier ou
>   l'assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=**3.3.0.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier
>   spécifié est introuvable.

However your package has the following configuration:

```
<package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
```

1. Are you sure both your unit test project and code are using the correct version of the assembly?
2. Do you have any assembly binding redirect in your App.config files? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013829/283787
3. Are they both using the same NuGet package?
4. Failing that you could use FusionLogger to see how the assembly is getting resolved.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your Package folder and remove all unused DLLs.
2. Compare the Package.Config file VS App.Config and make sure the versions maches

Answer (score -2):

I ran into a problem which is very similar to yours, the only difference is that I have built a custom library to generate several fake business mocks in my solution in order to reuse it in another tests.

I don't know how but a older version of Moq's dll appeared as a reference in one of my unit tests projects.

This is what solved my problem:

1. Remove all Moq NuGet packages in your test projects, check the package file to make sure no package config left for Moq and Castle were left.
2. Check your test projects References to make sure no legacy reference were forgotten there too. If Visual Studio didn't manage to do things right, remove it your self.
3. Close Visual Studio and navigate to your solution directory and look for a folder named "packages". Check if there is a folder named Moq. If so, delete it.
4. Reinstall the Moq packages via Package Manager Console or via the "Manage Nuget Packages" option for every test project dependent on Moq library.